# Sharekit and Facebook URL sharing

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I know there is a lot of these questions here, but Facebook seem to change their system now and then.
Is it possible to use Sharekit to send a URL to the status of the user (obviously with their permission) telling others about the app and with the URL for the app?

Every time I try to implement this I just end up in Facebook full on.  Can't even get back to my own app with a cancel button. I have followed several suggestions all over the Net with no success.

Would love to have the Facebook Share come up as a actionsheet within the app.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If you just wait for iOS 6, you would be able to use a super simple API to accomplish this!